# Retorno undefined de propriedade existente no model javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tenho um model bem definido, escrito desta maneira:

```
export class Navigation {
  line: {
    _id: string;
    code: string;
    name: string;
    isVia: boolean;
    _operator: {
      _id: string;
      name: string;
    };
    via: {
      _id: string;
      name: string;
    }
  };
  hour: string;
  destiny: string;
}
```

Em uma certa pagina estou iniciando em uma variavel antes do construtor e faço assim:

```
public navigation: Navigation = new Navigation();
```

Abaixo no `construtor` estou fazendo assim:

```
this.navigation.destiny = 'center';
this.navigation.line.isVia = false;
this.navigation.line.via.name = 'Nenhuma via para esta linha';
```

Consigo acessar as propriedade `hour` e `destiny` porém as propriedade por exemplo de linha não funciona. No meu console esta dando o seguinte erro:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'isVia' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'isVia' of undefined

Preciso utilizar os dados da model.

O que pode ser e como concertar ?

**TENTATIVAS**

1. public navigation: Navigation = {};
2. public navigation: Navigation = new Navigation;
3. public navigation: Navigation; e no construtor this.navigation = Navigation();

Ambas ocorrem o mesmo erro.

**SENÁRIO**

Estou desenvolvendo em `ionic 2` basicamente ele trabalha com `angular 4` e utiliza `typescript` como linguagem. Quando crio uma pagina no 'ionic 4' ele me gera arquivos em (`.html`, `.ts`, `.scss`, `.modeule.ts`) o arquivo `.ts` controla minhas paginas, nele consigo manipular facilmente todo meu `html`, fazendo requisições para o servidor e alterando na tela em tempo de execução facilmente. Para um melhor desenvolvimento utilizo a ideia de `models` para padronizar meu conteúdo tanto e recebimento quando de envio, baseado nisto tudo que recebo/envio tem a formulação de uma `model`. A model é um arquivo separado, no caso a minha está expressa em sua forma total (ou seja todo arquivo) em meu `.ts` de minha página estou instanciando este meu model, falando que minha variável `navigation` terá a forma de minha modelo `Navigation` logo após meu construtor tendo adicionar um valor, para como informei ascima utilizar em meu html. Neste momento estou tento o erro a qual expresso nesta pergunta.

Para reprodução do erro é necessário utilizar uma `model` "complexa" ou seja que tenha objeto de objetos, pode ser observado na minha que tenho valores na raiz (`destiny`, `hour`) e um objeto de `line` dentro deste objeto tenho outros, não consigo acessar este objeto de `line` e nada que tenha dentro dele.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro. Rodei no Playground e foi beleza. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: @Maniero Você esta reproduzindo errado, o erro acontesce quando é um objeto de objetos, como em meu exemplo. Eu consigo plenamente acessar destiny e hour que "esta na raiz do objeto" porém line que dentro dela tem _organization que é um objeto, via que também é objeto e ate mesmo isVia que esta dentro de line não é encontrado.

Comment: Se você não coloca o código em condições para gente testar e ver o erro a pergunta é que está errada.

Comment: Nao sou especialista em typescript, mas voce nao poderia usar classes aninhadas ao inves de simplesmente declarar um objeto dentro da classe?

Comment: Não me expressei mal vou passar o estado real.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e adicionar um código reproduzível

Answer (score 0):

A solução para meu problema foi mexer na classe.

```
export class Navigation {
  line: any = {
    _id: String,
    code: String,
    name: String,
    isVia: Boolean,
    _operator: {
      _id: String,
      name: String,
    },
    via: {
      _id: String,
      name: String,
    }
  };
  hour: String;
  destiny: String;
}
```

Isto acontesce porque meu model não estava conseguindo achar referencia do que era meu objeto de line, como nada o inicializava ele estava vazio, então tinha esta change ou então eu antes de setar um valor inicializava ele como {} desta forma `this.navigation.line = {}`

Qualquer uma das duas soluções resolveria meu problema.

Obrigado.